# FFMPEG - How to pipe RMS_level and pts_time metadata without generating unwanted metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to find the loudest (highest rms_level) moment in an audio file, but I need to pipe the metadata rather than write to a file.

I converted the answer found here: [https://superuser.com/questions/1183663/determining-audio-level-peaks-with-ffmpeg][1]

By removing the write to file command and adding a pipe. 
Here's what I've got.

```
ffmpeg -i loudSoft.mp3 -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level -f null - 2> result.txt
```

The only problem is, now I've got a lot of unwanted metadata before and after the RMS_level and pts_time data as well as `[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500]` being printed on each line. None of that was being written when I was writing to a file instead of piping. (all I need is the time and the rms.)

**Here is an abridged version of what I get when I write to file:**

```
frame:0    pts:0       pts_time:0
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-inf
frame:1    pts:47      pts_time:0.00106576
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-165.163347
frame:2    pts:1199    pts_time:0.0271882
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-99.736394
frame:3    pts:2351    pts_time:0.0533107
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-88.112282
frame:4    pts:3503    pts_time:0.0794331
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-86.554314
frame:5    pts:4655    pts_time:0.105556
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-82.977501
frame:6    pts:5807    pts_time:0.131678
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-79.698739
frame:7    pts:6959    pts_time:0.1578
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-76.629393
frame:8    pts:8111    pts_time:0.183923
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-71.581211
frame:9    pts:9263    pts_time:0.210045
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-75.038503
frame:10   pts:10415   pts_time:0.236168
```

**And here is what I'm looking at:**

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -fno-stack-check' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'loudSoft2.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.85, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] frame:0    pts:0       pts_time:0
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-inf
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 pcm_s16le
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] frame:1    pts:47      pts_time:0.00106576
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-165.163347
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] frame:2    pts:1199    pts_time:0.0271882
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-99.736394
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] frame:3    pts:2351    pts_time:0.0533107


*** MIDDLE OMITTED FOR BREVITY ***


[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-88.532185
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] frame:375  pts:430895  pts_time:9.77086
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-88.594276
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] frame:376  pts:432047  pts_time:9.79698
[Parsed_ametadata_1 @ 0x7f9d42c37500] lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-88.654138
size=N/A time=00:00:09.82 bitrate=N/A speed=82.6x    
video:0kB audio:1692kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Channel: 1
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] DC offset: 0.000001
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Min level: -0.000106
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Max level: 0.000115
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Min difference: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Max difference: 0.000077
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Mean difference: 0.000017
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS difference: 0.000022
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Peak level dB: -78.752617
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS level dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS peak dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS trough dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Crest factor: 3.126627
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Flat factor: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Peak count: 2
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Bit depth: 32/32
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Dynamic range: 76.274252
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Zero crossings: 246
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Zero crossings rate: 0.222624
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of NaNs: 0
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of Infs: 0
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of denormals: 0
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Channel: 2
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] DC offset: 0.000001
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Min level: -0.000106
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Max level: 0.000115
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Min difference: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Max difference: 0.000077
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Mean difference: 0.000017
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS difference: 0.000022
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Peak level dB: -78.752617
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS level dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS peak dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS trough dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Crest factor: 3.126627
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Flat factor: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Peak count: 2
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Bit depth: 32/32
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Dynamic range: 76.274252
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Zero crossings: 246
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Zero crossings rate: 0.222624
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of NaNs: 0
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of Infs: 0
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of denormals: 0
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Overall
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] DC offset: 0.000001
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Min level: -0.000106
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Max level: 0.000115
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Min difference: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Max difference: 0.000077
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Mean difference: 0.000017
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS difference: 0.000022
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Peak level dB: -78.752617
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS level dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS peak dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] RMS trough dB: -88.654138
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Flat factor: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Peak count: 2.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Bit depth: 32/32
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of samples: 1105
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of NaNs: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of Infs: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7f9d42c37280] Number of denormals: 0.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg logs **all** of its messages to stderr. By omitting the file option, the ametadata filter will send its output to the logger where it will be printed among other logs.

instead, set `file=-` and capture stdout.

Comment: That's great! Would you mind providing a code example?

Comment: If I do this: `ffmpeg -i loudSoft.mp3 -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=- 2> result.txt` then I just get the unwanted messages through the pipe, without any rms data.

Comment: Remove the 2 and keep the -f null -

Comment: Bonus question: How would I execute this same command with the fluent-ffmpeg package?